# OAuth, 403 response error on request_token

Tags: javascript, oauth, twitter-oauth

Receiving http 403 response error when trying to get a 
request token.

I've checked my base string's singing process, and that's proper.  If

I use the default keys on the Twitter dev site, it generates the same 
result as they list on the site, so i'm pretty sure that's okay.

Any insight would be much appreciated!

---

```
var reqURL = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token';
var reqNonce = getNonce();      
var reqTimeStamp = getTimeStamp();  
var reqSignatureMethod = 'HMAC-SHA1';
var reqOauthVersion = '1.0';
var reqConsumerKey = 'ySBPkqxaRlheQKFwejMpqg';
var reqConsumerSecret = '______________&'  // note the & at the end..
var reqCallback = 'http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3005%2Fthe_dance%2Fprocess_callback%3Fservice_provider_id%3D11'
var reqQuery = 'oauth_callback=' + reqCallback + '&oauth_consumer_key=' + reqConsumerKey + '&oauth_nonce=' + reqNonce + '&oauth_signature_method=' + reqSignatureMethod + '&oauth_timestamp=' + reqTimeStamp + '&oauth_version=' + reqOauthVersion;
var reqBaseString = 'POST&' + reqURL + '&' + encodeURIComponent(reqQuery);
var reqSignature = b64_hmac_sha1(reqConsumerSecret, reqBaseString);
var reqSignature = reqSignature + '=';
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function(data) {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {

        // Good response, got the xml file
        if (request.status == 200) {
            alert ('good response');
        }
    }
};

// alert (reqURL);
// alert (reqBaseString);

var oauthParams = encodeURIComponent("OAuth oauth_callback=\"" + reqCallback + "\",oauth_consumer_key=\"" + reqConsumerKey + "\",oauth_nonce=\"" + reqNonce + "\",oauth_signature_method=\"" + reqSignatureMethod + "\",oauth_timestamp=\"" + reqTimeStamp + "\",oauth_version=\"1.0\",oauth_signature=\"" + reqSignature + "\"");

request.open("POST", reqURL, true);
request.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/plain, */*");
request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", oauthParams);
request.send();
```

Comment: I recommend checking the [Netflix OAuth Tester](http://developer.netflix.com/resources/OAuthTest) using your own consumer key and secret.  Compare the signature base string generated by your code to the signature base string generated by the Netflix tester.  Let's see if there are any differences.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I did test my info with their library and it does work fine.  I'm in the process of getting their Ajax example to work with my keys.

Comment: where you able to solve it? I am facing similar issue.. please help

Answer (score 0):

What I have found to be immensely helpful is to just get the raw HTTP request that does work with the Netflix OAuth Test that cnauroth suggested and then compare it to what you are sending with this code snippet here.  OAuth is tricky and not fun so if you can just diff the two requests you should be able to find some improper encoding or a misplaced &.